# Blender adding unnecessary edges to flat surfaces

Tags: edges

I'm trying to make a beveled "B". I have a perfectly flat B that I'm extruding, but Blender keeps adding unnecessary lines. Scaling to Z 0, limited dissolve, etc will not remove them. Deleting them breaks the face.

These lines mess up the bevel process, even if I only select the 90 degree edges of the geometry. How do I force blender to just generate a flat, uninterrupted top surface?

[image]

Comment: Edges might seem unnecessary to you but they aren't unnecessary to geometry rendering process, even if in viewport. See https://devtalk.blender.org/t/faces-dissolving-problem/4419 and https://developer.blender.org/T68888. You can model that with curves instead / not convert from text and bevel that with their facility. Tldr though is "topology should be changed and don't overuse Ngons"

Comment: Is there any way to automatically create a topology that can be easily beveled? I don't want to have to carefully reconstruct the top layer of every letter in a sentence

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to bevel is not to convert the text to mesh, but to use bevels within the curve's geometry.

[image]

Converting curves (or text, which is another kind of curve) to mesh will almost always result in terrible topology.

Comment: This eliminates some problems I was having, but now the letters are getting "fat" and crowding into each other. Is there any way to constrain this setting to Z-axis only?